# Can I use my jailbroken device for testing?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an Apple developer account and want to test my application. I have recently jailbroken my device and want to use it for testing. Can I do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no restrictions in developing with a jailbroken device. Use it the same way as you would with a regular device.